# Tag a Firebase Crashlytics report with a unique ID

Tags: android, crashlytics

I would like to tag Firebase Crashlytics error report in my Android app with a generated unique ID for support purposes.
This ID must be used for only that specific error report and should be searchable via Firebase Crashlytics console.

What I tried to do is adding the ID into the message of the `Exception` and it shows up inside the error report:
[image]

However, when I search for the same ID in the console then the issue is not found:
[image]

Probably because instead of the top exception only the second exception is listed. I would wrap the exception into another one, but then it will be useless on the console because the actual root cause cannot be found out right away without opening each report. (Plus report grouping goes nuts.)

I also tried adding the ID as a custom key-value pair, which is possible to find by specifying the key name and value in the search box. But unfortunately if I remove the key after I send the error report then the report is not tagged with the key. If I don't remove it then all other error reports will also be tagged with the same key.